# Update SQL table with json object

Tags: sql, json

I have the following json object:-

{'follow_up_timestamp': '2021-09-21 22:16:36', 'id_fu': '', 'redcap_survey_identifier': '', 'nps': '76', 'improve': 'test', 'dowell': 'test', 'follow_up_complete': 'Complete', 'australian_hospital_patient_experience_question_se_timestamp': '[not completed]', 'more_qu': 'Yes', 'views': 'Always', 'needs': 'Always', 'unmet_need': '', 'cared': '', 'involvement': '', 'informed': 'Sometimes', 'team_communication': 'Sometimes', 'pain': '', 'confident': '', 'harm_distress': '', 'harm_discussed': '', 'quality': 'Average', 'comments': 'hhj', 'australian_hospital_patient_experience_question_se_complete': 'Incomplete'}

I want to place this into the json column of an SQL database - the column is JSON dtype nvarchar(max)

```
update Table_Json

SET JSON="{'follow_up_timestamp': '2021-09-21 22:16:36', 'id_fu': '','redcap_survey_identifier': '', 'nps': '76', 'improve': 'test', 'dowell': 'test', 'follow_up_complete': 'Complete', 'australian_hospital_patient_experience_question_se_timestamp': '[not completed]', 'more_qu': 'Yes', 'views': 'Always', 'needs': 'Always', 'unmet_need': '', 'cared': '', 'involvement': '', 'informed': 'Sometimes', 'team_communication': 'Sometimes', 'pain': '', 'confident': '', 'harm_distress': '', 'harm_discussed': '', 'quality': 'Average', 'comments': 'hhj', 'australian_hospital_patient_experience_question_se_complete': 'Incomplete'}"
```

but I am getting the following error.

Msg 103, Level 15, State 4, Line 3
The identifier that starts with '{'follow...... is too long. Maximum length is 128

I understood nvarchar(max) would store 2GB and nvarchar(8000) 8kb... my json object is certainly not that big.

New to SQL - obviously doing something stupid! please help!

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that it thinks the JSON string you provided is the name of a column, and column names cannot be longer than 128 characters. This is because you are using SET JSON=“blah blah blah” instead of SET JSON=‘blah blah blah’ (notice the difference between single quotes and double quotes).

When inserting a string into a SQL statement you must use single quotes ‘

This means you will have to change all the single quotes in your JSON string to double quotes “, or escape all the single quotes in the string to double-single-quotes ‘’